# celery error in connection with postgresql while django can

Tags: django, postgresql, celery, ubuntu-18.04

i used celery in my django project .django are running with uWSGI and can work with postgresql well but it's seem that celery can't connect to postgresql :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/classgram/www/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/classgram/www/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/classgram/www/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/classgram/www/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "hamclassy"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "hamclassy"
```

i'm working on host and host OS is Ubuntu 18.04 . thank you

Comment: Check if `hamclassy` user exists in Postgres.

Comment: And if `hamclassy` exists you'll need to check if the host that `celery` is running from is allowed to log in as `hamclassy`. Could be that the django host has access and celery doesn't.

Comment: @SergeyPugach : the `hamclassy` role exist.when i run `SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='hamclassy'` return `1` .

Comment: @azundo . how i can check it? sorry but i'm new in Unix OS terminal and i don't know enough about users and permissions.when running `htop` command i can see that `celery` and `uwsgi` both are running with user `classgram` , so what i must do to check if classgram can access postgresql or not?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Celery - it is obviously a typical PostgreSQL Access control issue.

Comment: @DejanLekic thank you for reply my question . what is difference between celery and django (uwsgi) configuration related to postgreSQL? i mean both of them are using `environment variable` to get `database_name`, `user` and `password` of postgreSQL. even i don't know how i can debug it :( and i just can read celery log.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I would assume that your PostgreSQL allows `hamclassy` to connect from machine where Django runs, but does not allow access from your Celery workers. The right place to look for solution to your problem is the `pg_hba.conf` file on the PostgreSQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with Celery - it is obviously a typical PostgreSQL Access control issue.

It seems like your PostgreSQL server allows `hamclassy` role (user) to connect from machine where Django runs, but does not allow access from your Celery workers. The right place to look for solution to your problem is the `pg_hba.conf` file on the PostgreSQL server.

On most Linux distributions `locate pg_hba.conf` should give you location of the file. Fedora has it here: `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`. Ubuntu on the other hand has it in /etc/postgresql. (Example: `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf`)